# Получить результат работы метода и сохранить в переменную

Tags: java, linux

Есть такой код, я передаю на вход два параметра и получаю в консоле результат работы этого метода, мне необходимо сохранить  результат в переменную как это сделать правильно ? Просьба помидорами не кидаться, буду рад любой помощи. 
Результат работы метода скрин.

Данное решение работает только Windows, необходимо чтоб работало и в Linux .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public static String activation(String serialNumber, String keyName) throws IOException, InterruptedException, SQLException {
    LocalDate futureDate = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(12);
    String formattedDate = futureDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
    String[] command =
            {
                    "cmd",
            };
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
    new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
    PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
    stdin.println("C:\\tdes_ecb.exe " + serialNumber + " " + keyName + " " + formattedDate);
    stdin.close();
    int returnCode = p.waitFor();
    String code = Integer.toString(returnCode);
    return code;
}

static class SyncPipe implements Runnable {
    public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        istrm_ = istrm;
        ostrm_ = ostrm;

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            byte[] b = new byte[1];

            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

            int c1 = 0;
            while ((c1 = istrm_.read()) > 0) {
                s.append((char) c1);

            }



            String[] aa = s.toString().split("\n");

            for (String retval : aa) {
                //  System.out.println("bbb:" + retval);
            }

            try {
                System.out.println(aa[4]);



            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

            }
```

Comment: вы ее и так сохранили в переменную `code`. Вы хотите сохранить ее на уроне класса?

Comment: Результат работы записывается сначала в буфер потом в масив.

Comment: Вы хотите из потока вернуть результат его работы, я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Да, Вы правильно поняли.

Comment: В json записать,потом считать.

Comment: Спасибо, но мне такой вариант  не подходит.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вам нужно из консоли получить результат работы и засунуть это значение в переменную Java?

Answer (score 1):

Может я чего то не так понял, но вроде бы речь идет о такой истории:

1. Есть некая внешняя процедура/метод/прога, которая принимает на вход некие параметры и результат работы выкидывает в консоль (назовем ее `tds_ecb`)
2. Далее, требуется написать прогу, которая бы результат работы п.1 помещала бы в свою переменную (назовем `tds_reader`)
3. Происходит все это безобразие в окружении Linux'а

В таком случае решается все достаточно просто:

1) Пишем `tds_reader`, который читает входящий поток из `System.in` приблизительно так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String input = br.readLine();
        //blah-blah
    }
```

2) Далее запускаем всю эту конструкцию примерно так:

```
tds_ecb <parm1> <parm2> | tds_reader
```

Работает это так: сначала запускается `tds_ecb` с некими параметрами, вывод в консоль оттуда перенаправляется на `System.in` проги `tds_reader` (на что указывает символ *pipe* `|`), который ее читает и помещает в переменную `input`

Используется понятие [pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)  стандартное средство межпроцессного взаимодействия в Linix (в Windows так же работает)

Answer (score 0):

Для получения значения из потока используйте интерфейс java.util.concurrent.Future, пример реализации можно посмотреть здесь https://www.baeldung.com/java-future

Вы не поставили в main ожидание завершения выполнения потока

```
...
while(!future.isDone()) {
     Thread.sleep(300);
}
String code = future.get();
...
```

Comment: Пробовал реализовать с помощью вашего ответа, но возвращается из метода всегда 0.

Comment: выложите ваш переделанный вариант

Comment: Выложил обновленный вариант.

Comment: Вы не поставили в main ожидание завершения выполнения потока. Добавил кусок кода в ответ

Comment: Что я только не делал но  "return code" всегда получаю 0.

Comment: `future.get()` и так блокирующая операция, `while isDone` не нужен перед вызовом `.get`

Answer (score 0):

Есть предложение использовать не обычный `thread`, а `executorService`. Тогда код будет выглядеть так

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<String> future = service.submit(new AsdCallable());
    String result = future.get(); // тут хранится ваш результат
}
```

**UPD**
чтобы получить результат работы программы (т.е. его вывод), надо зачитывать inputStream процесса:

```
static class AsdCallable implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        String serialNumber = "00240657F6DC6BCD9282";
        String keyName = "B97FF05A3585E44086BA357638348D8E";
        LocalDate futureDate = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(12);
        String formattedDate = futureDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern
        String[] command = {
                "C:\\tdes_ecb.exe", serialNumber, keyName, formattedDate
        };
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        readFromStream(p.getInputStream(), out); // зачитываем рез-ат работы

        StringBuilder err = new StringBuilder();
        readFromStream(p.getErrorStream(), err); // зачитываем ошибки

        int returnCode = p.waitFor();
        if (returnCode == 0) { //если процесс завершился успешно, выводим рез-ат работы
            return out.toString();
        }
        return err.toString(); // в противном случае выводим ошибки
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш вариант проверил  в действии, но результат "0"

Comment: ну так результат 0 - это нормальное завершение процесса. А вы что ожидаете?

Comment: Мне необходимо получить результат работы метода должно получится String 0024 55 24 A8 D4 82 53 A1 CF .

Comment: @НиколайГнап см апдейт ответа

Comment: new Thread(new TEstss.SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream()  Если  я Вас правильно понял вы предлагаете это не использовать. Но в таком случае не происходит запуск exe файла, то есть  и я не получу нужную мне информацию из метода.

Comment: запуск процесса у вас происходит в точке `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`. То, что вы делаете в другом потоке с инпутСтримом - никак не относится к запуску cmd. Вам вашу программу надо запускать в том же потоке, что и AsdCallable - по идее, вам не надо запускать отдельно cmd, а сразу запускать `"c:\\tdes_ecb.exe ... `. Обновил ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104018/discussion-between---and-andrew-bystrov).